# Pseudocode (or code) for main compression algorithms

Tags: image, video, compression

I'm really interested in image and video compression, but its hard for me to find a main source to start implementing the major algorithms.

What I want is just a source of information to begin the implementation of my own codec. I want to implement it from scratch (for example, for jpeg, implement my own Huffman, cosine conversion ...). All I need is a little step by step guide showing me which steps are involved in each algorithm.

I'm interested mainly on image compression algorithms (by now, JPEG) and video compression algorithms (MPEG-4, M-JPEG, and maybe AVI and MP4).

Can anyone suggest me an on-line source, with a little more information than wikipedia? (I checked it, but information is not really comprehensive)

Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Start with JPEG.  You'll need the [JPEG standard](http://www.jpeg.org/jpeg/index.html).  It will take a while to go through, but that's the only way to have a shot at writing something compatible.  Even then, the standard won't help much with deciding on how and how much you quantize the coefficients, which requires experimentation with images.

Once you get that working, then get the [H.264 standard](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-H.264-201201-I/en) and read that.

Answer (score 0):

[ImpulseAdventure site](http://www.impulseadventure.com/photo/) has fantastic series of articles about [basics of JPEG encoding](http://www.impulseadventure.com/photo/jpeg-quantization.html).

I'm working on an [experimental JPEG encoder](https://github.com/pornel/jpeg-compressor) that's partly designed to be readable and easy to change (rather than obfuscated by performance optimizations).